# Grails Dependency Injection Outside of Services?

Tags: spring, grails, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I have a Grails application that needs to run a strategy that will likely be swapped out over time. I know Spring underlies Grails, so I was wondering if I had access to Spring's IoC container so that I could externalize the actual dependency in an xml file (note: I have never actually done this, but just know of it, so I may be missing something). My goal is to be able to do something like the following:

```
class SchemaUpdateService {
public int calculateSomething(){
ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");
IStrategy strat = (IStrategy) ctx.getBean("mystrat");
}
}
```

And then map the appropriate implementation in the beans.xml file. I assume this is supported in Grails. Does anyone have any documentation on how this would work? Do I really just need the Spring IoC library and it will just work? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You define your beans in  `resources.xml` or `resources.groovy`.  The grails [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/14.%20Grails%20and%20Spring.html#14.2%20Configuring%20Additional%20Beans) is very clear about how to access the Spring application context.

Comment: Thanks so much. I think when I read through this the first time I didn't absorb any of it because I didn't have any context yet. Appreciate it!

Comment: @skaz, look at the FAQ at http://www.grails.org/FAQ , search for 'applicationContext' with your browser, it has some options too.

Answer (score 4):

You can access the application context from any Grails artefact using

```
ApplicationContext ctx = grailsApplication.mainContext
```

You can then use this to retrieve whichever beans you're interested in:

```
IStrategy strat = (IStrategy) ctx.getBean("mystrat")
```

In classes that don't have access to `grailsApplication`, you could use a helper such as the following to access the application context and the beans therein

```
class SpringUtils {

    static getBean(String name) {
        applicationContext.getBean(name)
    }

    static <T> T getBean(String name, Class<T> requiredType) {
        applicationContext.getBean(name, requiredType)
    }

    static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        ApplicationHolder.application.mainContext
    }
}
```

However, this should only be necessary if you need to retrieve different implementations of the same bean at runtime. If the required bean is known at compile-time, just wire the beans together in `resources.xml` or `resources.groovy`

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you want to define your strategy in your `grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy`:

```
beans = {
    myStrat(com.yourcompany.StrategyImpl) {
       someProperty = someValue
    }
}
```

Then, you simply `def` the a property with the same name into your service:

```
class SomeGrailsService {
    def myStrat

    def someMethod() {
        return myStrat.doSomething()
    }
}
```

In any Grails artefact (such as services and domain classes), Grails will automatically give the `myStrat` property the correct value. But don't forget, in a unit test you'll have to give it a value manually as the auto-wiring does not happen in unit tests.

Outside of a Grails artefact, you can use something like:

```
def myStrat = ApplicationHolder.application.mainContext.myStrat
```

In Grails 2.0, Graeme et al are deprecating the use of the `*Holder` classes (such as `ApplicationHolder` and `ConfigurationHolder`), so I'm not quite sure what the Grails 2.0 approach would be...