# How can I split domain logic and data access in Grails

Tags: grails, dns, domain-driven-design, persistence, hexagonal-architecture

How can I split domain logic and data access in Grails (and is it a good idea)?

Many software applications we write are rather data(base) centered and in Grails one often persist from service classes or controllers directly to a database configured in DataSource.groovy. It is easy to change database, but we are not really independent of the persistence implementation in the code.

I am trying to write an application that opens for different persistence and data source (not only database) implementations and focus on the business domain instead of database entities. This is also a plus when testing (easy to write fake/mock persistence)
Initially I have only one persistence implementation - Grails domain classes, using GORM. But it is a possibility that I in the future would like to have other data sources than a database, for example rest services or something else.

For now, I only have the database as data source though and do mostly crud stuff (and some domain logic). I think I am still in a way stuck in "old" thinking, focused on database persistence, because most of my business domain classes, have a Grails domain class equivalent that is a copy of it. When domain classes are to be persisted, I just copy the properties to the Grails domain class.

I am not very happy with this solution. I can think of at least two possible improvements/changes:

1. My Grails domain classes could be organised more differently from the business domain classes, so I don't just copy properties from one class to the other. This will still involve a lot of property mapping from one class to the other when reading or writing from/to the database though.
2. Maybe there is a way to use business domain classes, from a regular src/main/groovy package and decorate with GORM stuff? Or in some other way split the domain logic and persistence? I have seen it is possible to do this by using hibernate conf over the domain classes. Is this the only way?

I have seen some interesting discussions of Grails architecture, including clean architecture, hexagonal architecture and ddd, but I have not found any examples yet. Are there any?

At this point, as I said, much of the functionality is CRUD stuff, but not everything. And further on, the application may have more business logic, so I would prefer not to use the "default" architecture of Grails with views, controllers, services, domain. I want a "core" application that is in a way independent of grails view/controllers and domain/GORM

Comment: Maybe I can use a base class and extend it in both the Grails domain folder and the business domain folder...

Comment: GORM itself is very "pluggable" and, as you probably are aware, many backing implementations already exist: Mongo, Hibernate, Neo4j, Redis, etc.  (take a look at https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping)  As long as you steer clear of HQL and native SQL (prefer dynamic finders and where queries), it's possible to move between implementations without huge code changes.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Andrew. Yes GORM is pluggable, but if possible, I am trying to be independent of database as persistence. So it should be a repository that can be anything (i.e. a mock, a file system etcetera). Maybe my database model should not look like the business domain at all. I have to consider that at least.

Comment: Right, a couple of additional thoughts: 1) Take a look at http://grails.org/plugin/gorm-rest-client for one example of GORM's extreme flexibility  and 2) Command Objects are a powerful concept that might help in your efforts, see for example: http://skillsmatter.com/podcast/groovy-grails/all-hail-the-command-object-are-stateless-services-the-only-way

Comment: I will @Andrew. Appreciate it! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's been some time since you posted your question, but this is a very interesting topic for me...

I currently work in big-ish Java8 projects that implement principles of clean architecture, ddd, cqrs and hexagonal architecture among others. I also have limited experience with Grails 1.x projects and I remember asking the same questions as you are now.

Now that I have a broader perspective, I honestly think that it doesn't make sense to force Grails into a clean architecture. You're going to have a very painful time trying to achieve it and you probably won't be pleased with the result.

Everything in Grails is designed to be used in an opinionated, convention based way. Starting with GORM being an ActiveRecord implementation and following by every little decision that they've made about directory structure, semantics on artifacts that you need to define (controllers, services, models...), etc.. I'm not saying this is bad. In fact, this is great when you're developing something that fits into this schema-of-things.

This coupling and implicit behavior between your artifacts makes really hard to model your business logic apart from your data access (or your http interaction, or any other interaction with third parties for that matter).

From a DDD point of view you should favor data or collection based Repositories over ActiveRecord implementations. Then you can start separating your persistence logic from your Domain model. Trying to do this while maintaining ActiveRecord-like interaction with your persistence layer is going to produce a very "dirty" layer of adaptation with lots of repetition.

You will have a really hard time especially while trying to adapt complex Domain with aggregate objects that should go into different database tables, for example.

Now, addressing the two improvements that you suggest, this is what I can tell you about them:

> 1. My Grails domain classes could be organised more differently from the business domain classes, so I don't just copy properties from one class to the other. This will still involve a lot of property mapping from one class to the other when reading or writing from/to the database though.

You can indeed do what you say. Just place some code on src/groovy folder. The main problem that you will face here is dependency injection. Grails automagically injects dependencies on your services and controllers when they're defined in the standard directories. For everything else, you need to explicitly [tell Grails how to take dependencies and pass them to your custom artifacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7350266/grails-dependency-injection-outside-of-services).

> 2. Maybe there is a way to use business domain classes, from a regular src/main/groovy package and decorate with GORM stuff? Or in some other way split the domain logic and persistence? I have seen it is possible to do this by using hibernate conf over the domain classes. Is this the only way?

If you decorate your Domain objects defined in src/groovy with GORM (if it is even possible) you will have the same problem. Your mission here is to isolate your Domain from the persistence logic. Doing so by having any GORM in it fails its purpose.

Everything considered my advice here would be to:

1. switch to other less coupled libraries that let you desing your own architecture (i.e. [Ratpack](http://ratpack.io/), [Jooq](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.5/manual/getting-started/jooq-and-groovy/)) or
2. if that is not an option, just embrace the Grails-way-to-do-things completely.

There is a very comprehensive list of libraries that you can browse for inspiration: [Awesome Java](https://github.com/akullpp/awesome-java)

Comment: thanks for your comments. I appreciate your thoughts and I think you are probably right, that one should embrace the Grails-way. Up to now, I have done that too. But I haven't dropped these thoughts though :)
Actually, placing domain logic in src/main/groovy is something I tried out, but in this case, I ended up with most of the code in services - the "standard" Grails way.

Comment: Some ideas:
1) One could have ddd-like solution with domain logic in src/main/groovy, called from Grails services and/or controllers and this logic could call the GORM-stuff that is an implementation of a Repository interface? This would involve copying data, but that is the case without Grails as well. 
2) If there is a one-to-one mapping between domain & database tables,one could place the domain classes in the standard Grails domain folder. Then the domain logic could be separated and put in src/main/groovy and objects (data+domain logic) could be created runtime. 
Any thoughts @ggalmazor?